# How do I get Spotlight attributes to display in the get info window?

Tags: cocoa, spotlight

I have created a spotlight importer for comic files.  The attributes are successfully imported and searchable.  The one thing that remains is getting the attributes to display in a file's get info window.

It seems that this should be a simple matter of editing the schema.xml file so the attributes are nested inside displayattrs tags. Unfortunately this does not seem to be working.

I simplified the plugin for testing.  The following are all of the important files.

schema.xml

```
<types>
<type name="cx.c3.cbz-archive">  
    <allattrs>
        kMDItemTitle
        kMDItemAuthors
    </allattrs>
    <displayattrs>
        kMDItemTitle
        kMDItemAuthors
    </displayattrs>
    </type>
<type name="cx.c3.cbr-archive">  
    <allattrs>
        kMDItemTitle
        kMDItemAuthors
        </allattrs>
    <displayattrs>
        kMDItemTitle
        kMDItemAuthors
    </displayattrs>
</type>
</types>
```

GetMetadataForFile.m

```
Boolean GetMetadataForFile(void* thisInterface, 
                       CFMutableDictionaryRef attributes, 
                       CFStringRef contentTypeUTI,
                       CFStringRef pathToFile)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    NSString * file = (NSString *)pathToFile;
    NSArray * authors = [[UKXattrMetadataStore stringForKey: @"com_opencomics_authors" atPath: file traverseLink: NO] componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    [(NSMutableDictionary *)attributes setObject: authors forKey: (id)kMDItemAuthors];
    NSString * title = [UKXattrMetadataStore stringForKey: @"com_opencomics_title" atPath: file traverseLink: NO];
    [(NSMutableDictionary *)attributes setObject: title forKey: (id)kMDItemTitle];
    [pool release];
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Plugin works just fine search-wise, but no custom Finder Get Info

Comment: Ah - problem was wrong location of *schema.xml* in my case (see below)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a `</types>` tag. Copy/paste error in writing the question, or is it missing in the XML file, too?

If it's missing in the file, the XML is invalid.

Comment: Screwed up the stack overflow formatting.
I ran mdcheckschema on it during my troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

What does your **plugin folder structure** look like?

It should be something like this (taken from *QuartzComposer*) in order for the *schema.xml* to be found and processed by the Spotlight importer process:

```
Contents
   Info.plist
   MacOS
      QuartzComposer
   Resources
      schema.xml
   version.plist
```